# Zsh auto complete suggest complete functions (_git _vim etc)

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have a small annoyance with how `zsh` is doing complete suggestions for my commands.

If I type the beginning of a command that I don't have installed and press `tab` it will suggest the completion function that is installed.

Lets say I want to execute `vim` but it isn't installed it will suggest `_vim`.

Is there a way to turn this off? Or have I done something wrong in my setup?

All my dotfiles are public at `github.com/henrikbjorn/castle`.

Comment: I've seen this behaviour before, but in my current setup it doesn't seem to be present. Sadly, I have no clue, which of my settings changed that behaviour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, zsh's completion engine only tries to append something to what you type. You configured it to try adding a prefix as well. The simple interactive completion configuration engine (`compinstall`) offers this under “matching control → substring completion”. This inserts a line like this in your `.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
```

The [`zstyle`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-zstyle) builtin sets (mostly) completion settings. The [`matcher-list`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-matcher_002dlist_002c-completion-style) completion style is a list of ways to try in succession, stopping when there is at least one match. The empty string means the default completion (suffixes only). The [matching control](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Matching-Control) incantation `l:|=* r:|=*` means to try a prefix matching `*` and a suffix matching `*`, i.e. any prefix and suffix.

You can forbid prefixes that begin with `_` altogether. This still allows completion of words that begin with `_`, and completion by adding a prefix, but the prefix may not start with `_`.

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'l:|=[^_]* r:|=*'
```

This applies to all completions, not just completions of command names. I don't know how to restrict this to command names.

There should be a way to more precisely exclude command names that begin with `_`, but I don't know how. A first start is with the [`ignored-patterns`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-ignored_002dpatterns_002c-completion-style) completion style.

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:*' ignored-patterns '_*'
```

This excludes matches that begin with `_`; however, if there are no matches, then zsh tries again without the ignore rules. The good of this is that if the command started with an underscore in the first place, it will be completed in this second pass. The bad part is that zsh will thus try adding an underscore anyway if there are no matches, so if you have `vi` and `view` but not `vim` then pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> after `vi` will offer `vi` and `view` but not `_vim`, but if you type `vim` then completion will offer `_vim`.

Comment: Thanks seems to work by doing one of the solutions you specified, also i learned a bunch about the way it works.

Comment: The solution with `ignore-patterns` works just fine for me, even if there are no matches. Just had to make sure that `completer` does not contain `_ignored`.